# Facebook Graph API Insights, what is max date range in "since" to "until"

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-insights

I've tried and found that if the "since" and "until" dates are bigger then around 90 days the result is an error on the {page-id}/insights edge. Is there any documentation to what the max difference can be, I can't find it.

I'm using v2.2 of the graph api and the error is on the request is:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "Unsupported operation",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 100
  }
}
```

Example of call:

```
/v2.2/{page-id}/page_stories?period=week&since=2013-11-01&until=2014-12-02
```

Answer (score 3):

From what I've found it's a maximum of 93 days. Haven't seen any info about that from Facebook itself though.